# Beginner Web scraping question(extract values for the same pattern of code)

Tags: python, web-scraping

Would like to ask how can I extract the value "1" in <,span>1</s pan> in the below HTML code?(This is just a part of the whole code, I will do a for loop later on for extracting all values between  and  as the remaining part of code follows the same pattern. Thanks!

````
    <div class="ipl-ratings-bar">
            <span class="rating-other-user-rating">
            <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            </svg>
                <span>1</span><span class="point-scale">/10</span>
            </span>
    </div>```




My code:
ratetable=info_results.find_all('div', {'class': 'ipl-ratings-bar'}) 
valuetable=ratetable.find_all('span')

It ends up showing ```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```
````

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth learning about xpaths for such problems.

```
In [1]: from lxml import html

In [2]: string = '''<div class="ipl-ratings-bar">
   ...:             <span class="rating-other-user-rating">
   ...:             <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" widt
   ...: h="24">
   ...:                 <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
   ...:                 <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
   ...:                 <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
   ...:             </svg>
   ...:                 <span>1</span><span class="point-scale">/10</span>
   ...:             </span>
   ...:     </div>'''

In [3]: root = html.fromstring(string)

In [4]: root.xpath('//div[@class="ipl-ratings-bar"]/span/span[1]/text()')
Out[5]: ['1']
```